# How do I unite these mysql queries? Does it make sense to do so?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building general statistics for my DB.

I want to know how to unite so many SELECTS so that I get result in 1 row different columns.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_users FROM users;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_verified FROM users WHERE verified = 1;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_passed_tut FROM users WHERE level = 3;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_private FROM users WHERE privacy = 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_friends_only FROM users WHERE privacy = 2;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_public FROM users WHERE privacy = 3;
```

And does it make sense to do this? Or should I rather do seperate queries and save to an array 1 by 1?

Comment: You can do subqueries or unions

Comment: @JohnConde which is recommended way? or better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_users,
       sum(verified = 1) as total_verified,
       sum(level = 3) as total_passed_tut,
       sum(privacy = 0) as total_private,
       sum(privacy = 2) as total_friends_only,
       sum(privacy = 3) as total_public
FROM users;
```

Comment: This looks cleaner than other solution.

Comment: And it does not need to execute subqueries

Comment: Unrelated question, but  sum(created < (NOW() - NOW(seven days ago))) as total_registered_seven_days, How do i do get number of users registered in last 7 days? I want to know syntax of NOW(seven days ago)

Comment: nvm NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_users FROM users) as `total_users`,
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_verified FROM users WHERE verified = 1) as `total_verified`,
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_passed_tut FROM users WHERE level = 3) as `total_passed_tut`,
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_private FROM users WHERE privacy = 0) as `total_private`,
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_friends_only FROM users WHERE privacy = 2) as `total_friends_only`,
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_public FROM users WHERE privacy = 3) as `total_public`
FROM dual
```